# Is it possible to drive a relay with 220VAC coil without a triac?

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, triac

Can I drive this relay [RT314730](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/418/6/ENG_DS_RT1_1120-736188.pdf) directly with [MOC3041M](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/moc3043m-d.pdf)?
I want to save some space and money.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will probably work. You may need an RC snubber to get it to commutate reliably with an inductive load like that.

Keep in mind that 400V is a bit marginal with 220VAC mains anyway, so I would suggest [MOC3163](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/moc3163m-d.pdf) series which has better dv/dt immunity and 600V breakdown rating. And I'd still use a snubber.

Comment: A 100Ω and 100nF will suffice, right?

Comment: @ElectronSurf Sounds appropriate, yes.

Comment: I used 100nF and 100Ω and on power up the relay latched, I then changed RC to 100Ω and 10nF and the relay was oscillating. increasing R to 33KΩ (equal to the relay coil resistance) solved the problem but is it ok?

Comment: Did you use the 600V opto ?

Comment: I used MOC3063, couldn't find 3163.

Answer (score 8):

The Opto Triac that you linked contains a 400 V triac. This is marginal for a 220 VAC line (220 * 1.707 = 375 V). You should use an Opto Triac from the MOC3163 Series, they are rated for 600 V.

Comment: 22 seconds late. +1 OP should note the consensus though.